# FadeIn Span after checking value of <select> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm the developer for my school's [Virtual Enterprises](https://veinternational.org/about/) class. I'm need some help with the code for our website [www.modernnook.com](http://modernnook.com).

The problem I'm facing is that I need to check what the value of a `select` element is equal to and fade in a span that will contain a string + a variable that depends on the value of the `select`. Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/McLemore/c6ya76u1/1/).

Click on the picture with Your Nook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
<select id="choice">
 <option value="">--Select any value--</option>
 <option value="hello">Hello</option>
 <option value="hi">Hi</option>
 <option value="bye">Bye</option></select><h2 id="here">...</h2>
<style type="text/css"> #here{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .6s;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var choice = document.getElementById("choice");
var here = document.getElementById("here");
choice.addEventListener("change", alerte);
function alerte(){
    here.style.opacity = '1';
    here.innerHTML = "The value is : "+choice.value;
}</script>
```

**Choice** is your select* id.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved my own problem. My code worked just fine as is except I hadn't defined the id of the `select` element. Let this be a lesson to all. PROOFREAD, PROOFREAD, PROOFREAD!